# access list using angular

Tags: list, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve list . I used below code

```
 $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/MyList",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        debugger;
        $scope.customers = data.d.results;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

But when code executes i get wiered data in `data` variable. I get information of whole page which is all html. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am getting the below error. can some one help me. Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are not calling the REST api "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')", the url you are calling returns the the ListView (AllItems.aspx) page.
Change the url to `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/getByTitle("MyList")/items'`

Comment: ok now i am not getting wiered data. But i get undefined when i do data.d.results

Comment: are you trying to load list items or list properties? the endpoint for listitems is "_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/getByTitle("MyList")/items

Comment: just a last question. What if i wanted to retrieve item based on some criteria?

Comment: you can use the $filter url parameters to filter the data based on a condition(similar to CAML conditions), there are many parameters you can use with REST, here are the operators and usage. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx  and http://adicodes.com/sharepoint-rest-interface-with-operators-and-functions/